# Hide Related list on parent Page layout for users not in Opportunity Team

Tags: page-layout, related-list, master-detail

I need to hide related list on opp page layout for users who are not an opp Team member.
The related list is a custom child object XYZ[Detail] of opportunity[Master].

How to implement it ?
Please suggest.